# Rails/Rspec: Testing uniqueness validations in models without touching the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I current test uniqueness validations in rspec using something like the following:

```
@unique = Unique.create!(:unique_field => 'unique_value')
Unique.new(:unique_field => 'unique_value').should_not be_valid
```

Ideally, I'd like to get my nose out of the database for uniqueness validations. Any ideas how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validates_uniqueness_of` does not guarantee the absence of duplicate record insertions, because uniqueness checks on the application level are inherently prone to race conditions[more](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of). To get around this problem you might define unique index on on your unique field or write some workaround to have tests that don't depend on your database however I don't see any point in writing these tests. You'll just have some useless code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the unique value dynamically by editing your factory to change every time you run test

for example

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:username) { |n| "foo#{n}" }
  f.password "foobar"
  f.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
end
```

iHope it helpful , good luck

source : [Railscasts Episode #158: Factory Girl](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158)